# Why do we have the following equality $\sigma(z)=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_if(w_i)e^{w_iz}$

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $\mu=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\delta_{w_i}$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac measure, and $\lambda_i,w_i\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\lambda_i$ is non-zero. Let $\sigma_k$ be Fourier coefficients of $f$:
$$
\sigma_k=\dfrac{1}{2T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2} f(x)e^{-2\pi i k x}d\mu.
$$
Then why do we have the following equality:
$$
\sigma(z)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\sigma_k\dfrac{z^k}{k!}=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_if(w_i)e^{w_iz}?
$$

---

My work:

\begin{align}
\sigma(z)&=\dfrac{1}{2T}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\dfrac{z^k}{k!}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}f(x)e^{-2i\pi (kx)}d \mu\\
    &=\dfrac{1}{2T}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\dfrac{z^k}{k!}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}f(x)e^{-2i\pi (kx)}d \left({\sum_{i=1}^{r}\lambda_i\delta_{w_i}} \right)\\
    &=\dfrac{1}{2T}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\dfrac{z^k}{k!}\sum_{i=1}^r\lambda_if(w_i)e^{-2i\pi (kw_i)}\\
    &=\dfrac{1}{2T}\sum_{i=1}^{r}\lambda_if(w_i)\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\dfrac{z^k}{k!}e^{-2i\pi kw_i}\\
    &\stackrel{?}{=}\sum_{i=1}^{r}\lambda_if(w_i)e^{w_iz}
\end{align}

I don't know where the mistake is in my reasoning or am I misunderstanding something? Can you help me please? Thank you very much.